# Yoast breadcrumb plugin showing 1

Tags: php, css, wordpress, breadcrumbs

I am using the Yoast SEO Wordpress plugin and am implementing breadcrumbs on my site for some reason I have 2 issues I cannot seem to resolve.

1. After adding the following code a number '1' shows up and I cannot get rid of it... See http://alanbrandt.com/portfolio/
2. All pages have the same post name part from the posts root site? Why does it always show the same post title on all pages? (Home > Portfolio > Daydreaming…)

Here is the code:

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <?php 
    if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') ) {
        $breadcrumbs = yoast_breadcrumb('<p class="breadcrumbs_p">','</p>');
        echo $breadcrumbs;
    } 
    ?>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Hope some one can help!

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the source

```
/**
  * Template tag for breadcrumbs.
  *
  * @param string $before  What to show before the breadcrum
  * @param string $after   What to show after the breadcrumb.
  * @param bool   $display Whether to display the breadcrumb (true) or return it (false).
  * @return string
  */
```

You want to do:

```
$breadcrumbs = yoast_breadcrumb('<p class="breadcrumbs_p">','</p>', false);
```

or do the following and not echo.

```
yoast_breadcrumb('<p class="breadcrumbs_p">','</p>');
```

Comment: Thanks... That was part 1 resolved... :) Do you have any idea why I get the same post name on all the breadcrumb trails?

Comment: I don't know why its showing like that without seeing how it is set up. Do you have portfolio set up as a parent page for your other pages? Also, you really don't need a breadcrumb if you have one level of navigation.

Comment: The breadcrumb is for SEO purposes... Portfolio is by root blog post site. However contacts, prices and all the other pages are just static pages.

Comment: I personally wouldn't mess with the layout. I don't think it's going to help your rankings.